# Issue with div functionaility if content is served via JQuery and not hardcoded

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic-content

My problem is probably easiest explained from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L3zVY/7/

If you click the image in the top right of the box, the boxes fade away (image isn't present so it's just a question mark).

If I try and dynamically manipulate these boxes instead of them being hardcoded then this functionality is lost for some reason.

The reason I am doing it this way is because I have a login page using a box that changes class depending on the error message. Everything works fine except for being able to close the box...

Any ideas?

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Close notifications (fade and slideup)

        $(".notification a.close").click(function () {
            $(this).parent().fadeTo(400, 0, function () {
                $(this).slideUp(200);
            });
            return false;
        });


// JQuery Broken Notification:
    $("#msgbox1").html('Broken :( <a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/notification_close.png" alt="close" /></a>');

});
```

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code *in the question* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to help you. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for you now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the question, we ensure that the question (and its answers) remain useful for a reasonable period of time.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by, "dynamically manipulate"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/L3zVY/8/  You need to use the live() function with jquery.

Answer (score 2):

When you assign the `click` handler, the element you insert does not exist yet, hence jQuery cannot find it.

Either insert the element first:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#msgbox1").html('...');
    $(".notification a.close").click(...);
});
```

or use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) / [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".notification").delegate('a.close', 'click', function(){...});
    $("#msgbox1").html('...');
});
```

---

Event handlers are always bound to the element. You cannot bind anything to something that does not exist. `live`/ `delegate` overcome this problem by binding an event handler further up the DOM tree (possible because of [*event bubbling*](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)) and checking the target of the event.